# Is there a way to get a reference to all the paragraphs or headings in a web page in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm writing a simple Greasemonkey script to strip out all the images, headings and paragraphs from a web page (it's because someone wants to use images of several popular websites with the images and text removed in a presentation about branding of websites). I've figured out how to do so with images by using a for loop and the document.images array like this:

```
var i = 0;
var imglngth = document.images.length;

for(i=0;i<imglngth;i++)
{
    document.images[i].style.display="none";
}
```

However, I don't believe there's an object representing paragraphs or headers. Any suggestions as to how I could implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery would be very each to get all the `<p>` elements.

```
$('p').each(function(){
   // do stuff
});
```

[Here's](http://joanpiedra.com/jquery/greasemonkey/) a link for some info on jQuery and GreaseMonkey

Comment: As long as you can include the jquery script, it may. It's worth a shot?

Comment: Thanks, that worked OK. It's very rough and ready as I haven't really used jQuery, and I can't get it to work in Chrome, but it works perfectly in Firefox and as long as it works in one browser it should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

If the headers are in `<h1>` - `<h6>` tags, you can use the [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.getElementsByTagName) method from the DOM API, and a loop to get everything from `<h1>` to `<h6>`.

```
for( i = 1; i<= 6; i++ ) { 
    var tag = 'h' + i;
    var heads = document.getElementsByTagName( tag );
    for ( j = 0; j < heads.length; j++ ) { 
        heads[j].style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

If the document does not use header tags, you may have to reverse-engineer their stylesheet and do something with a bit more logic.

Of course, manually traversing the DOM API can be a pain. If you can use something like jQuery, it's a bit easier:

```
$( ':header' ).each( function() { ... } );
```

Comment: FYI Greasemonkey scripts can use `Array.forEach` to iterate a NodeList. Also, jQuery has the `":header"` psuedo selector for your hx tag selector there.

Comment: The jQuery selector should be `h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6` (note the commas)

Comment: I would not generally use `:header` unless I had to (eg. to do `:header+:header`, which would be an unpleasant rule to express without it). As this is a non-standard selector, it forces jQuery to use the slow JavaScript Sizzle library instead of the fast `querySelectorAll` method built into modern browsers.